# More than one belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m new to Rails and I’ve been reading Michael Hartl’s tutorial and I am not sure if I’m doing this correctly. I have Users, Posts, and Categories:

Users can create Posts and Categories

A Post can be assigned to only one Category.

Currently, when the User creates a post they type in the Category (let’s just say the Category will always exist in the database) and from there it looks up the ID of the Category and passes that along to the post creation. This is what I’m running to create the post and assign it to a Category in my Post_Controller:

```
category_id = Category.find_by_name(post_params[:category])
@post = current_user.posts.build(title: post_params[:title], content: post_params[:content], category_id: category.id)
```

My question is: Is this the proper way to enter data with two belong_to’s? I’ve dug around and I can’t find a simple answer to this. To me it seems that passing a category ID like this is not secure but I don’t know of another way to do this. Here’s my basic Model information (just the belong_to’s, has_many, etc). Please let me know if you need more:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    has_many :posts
    has_many :categories

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible  :title,  :content, :category_id
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    belongs_to :users
    has_many :posts
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {maximum:30}
    validates :user_id, presence: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the proper way to enter data with two belong_to’s?

It's fine.  Does it work?  If it works, it's fine.  Maybe there are things you could do to tighten it up later, if you find you're making the `Category.find...` call a lot, but, you're also just starting, so don't worry about stuff like that too much.

> To me it seems that passing a category ID like this is not secure but I don’t know of another way to do this.

Again, don't worry about that too much at the moment.  If you want to read up on Rails security, though, take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

Comment: if it helped please check the answer so it's taken out of the 'unanswered' queue :)  cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If all the information you need to create a new post is in `post_params`, it seems you're doing that `Category.find_by_name` unnecessarily. You should be collecting the `category_id` in your params rather than the category's name.

And then in your `PostsController`:

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
```

Just remember to allow `:category_id` along with the other regular attributes in your `post_params` and you'll be golden.

Comment: I'm guessing that `category` in `post_params` is actually a string, hence `find_by_name`.

Comment: For sure. But must it be?

Comment: Yes, category in post_params is a string and, no, it doesn't have to be. I was just using a string as an example but this is easily changed in my project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool! If you find out that the answer was useful, please don't forget to pick it as the correct one.